# How to get rid of ad.doubleclick.net malware?

Tags: malware

I can't get rid of `ad.doubleclick.net` malware from my PC.

I am using Firefox and it seems that all links that lead to `www.googleadservices.com` are redirected to `https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/***` which can't load it self.

So if I click the below link

[image]

I get this result:

[image]

I tried AdwCleaner from Malwarebytes but it did not find any malware on my PC. I also disabled all add ons. There is no `ad.doubleclick` software installed on my PC that I could remove.

This problem happens in Firefox aswell as in Chrome (I have only those two to test).

Any suggestions how I can get rid of this?

Comment: Nuke it from orbit.

Comment: @MechMK1 Do you mean with a missile?

Comment: Nuke it from orbit means completely re-installing it from scratch. Back up your data and merge it back step by step, ensuring that it doesn't re-infect your new installation again.

Comment: It definitely is a malware... Google tracking everyone, horrible... I just added this ad.doubleclick.net in drivers/etc/hosts file to block it.
Only CHROME browser is doing this.
When I open the site in Firefox it is NOT there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ad.doubleclick.net is not malware. It’s an advertising link retuned by Google to redirect your browser to the desired site. DoubleClick is Google’s advertising company. They use this referral scheme in order to track your browsing habits (to learn what words you searched for that led you to click on their ad), and for Google to collect a referral bonus for displaying such a good advertisement that you clicked on it. You are just seeing an error because your browser can’t get to their servers.

The error you’re seeing is because you have ad.doubleclick.net blocked in your computer somehow. You may be browsing using a “proxy” that is blocking that address; your router or firewall may be blocking the doubleclick.net domain; you may have blocked doubleclick in your hosts file; you may have installed a DNS ad blocker like pi-hole; or maybe you have installed any number of tools that might block these requests.

Comment: Thank you. You were right, the domain was blocked in my `hosts` file from the tool `Spybot Anti-Beacon`. To change my hosts file, I had to allow host access in ZoneAlarm https://superuser.com/a/1104284/236337. Although this is not a malware, there are some articles saying that this is a maleware https://praxistipps.chip.de/ad-doubleclick-net-entfernen-so-klappts_45351.

Comment: Actually, doubleclick.net *IS* malware. It soaks up incredible amounts of CPU time and crashes my browser to boot. Even if unintentional, how is that not malware?

Comment: @Bruce , while I agree that doubleclick.net is a privacy stealing, resource wasting, security plagued, economy draining, scam ridden, unethical, unwanted, and unwelcome pustule on the ass of the internet, they technically aren’t illegal.  Therefore it doesn’t meet the test of malware.

Comment: Then we have different definitions of malware. If it does MALicious things that you don't want done and it is softWARE, it's MALWARE. :)

Comment: Agree, if it does not GOOD for the user then its malware, crapware, bloatware, an any other non-good software is malware

Answer (score 0):

What you describe doesn't mean you have any malware. There can be bug on the Doubleclick side.

To remove such links, install any ad blocker of your choice (uBlock Origin or Ad Block Plus or similar).